# Biztalk server FTP Receive Port Error. I dont know why this port is disabled sometimes

Tags: c#, ftp, integration, biztalk, biztalk-2010

In my application I have an FTP receive location. Sometimes this port is disabled but I dont know what causes this port to be disabled. Moreover, I found below error in windows application logs.

A message received by adapter "BiztalkMessagingEngine" on receive location "XXX" with URI "ZZZ" is suspended.   Error details: The InboundTransportLocation is disallowed. This could be because the receive location is disabled or its service window is currently inactive. biztalk ftp adapter.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what is the situation when such errors occur? And which port are you talking about? Is it the ftp control channel or some dynamic data channel? Sorry, there is not enough information here to help...

Comment: Did any of these help: http://synthesisconsulting.net/blog/2012/3/16/the-inboundtransportlocation-is-disallowed.html

Comment: An empty file is send to the system. Then this file goes to suspended situation but in my opinion, this does not cause receive location being disabled. And I don't have more information about error. Maybe some people has faced this problem before.

Comment: I am not sure if my answer is valid in your scenario, but, after a lot of ping, our FTP server was rejecting connection from the Port, which caused it to shut down.  May be you might want to check your FTP logs.